# Prove that $\int^1_0 \frac{dx}{x^x} = 1+ \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^3}...$.

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

> Prove that $\int^1_0 \frac{dx}{x^x} = 1+ \frac{1}{2^2} +
> \frac{1}{3^3}...$

**Darboux theorem (integral) :** 
 Whatever the number $x(k,n) \in [a + \frac{k-1}{n}(b-a),a + \frac{k}{n}(b-a),]$, we have $$\int^b_af(x)dx = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{b-a}{n} \sum^n_{k=1}f(x(k,n))$$

This is one of the questions we presented in one session to contest preparation PUTNAM. It turns out that I can't get from the problem. Is anyone is able to give me a hint related to Darboux theorem? (Please, don't give me the answer. Simply, an argument that can help me advance in the problem or theorem might suffice.)

Comment: Here, it doesn't have the Darboux theorem as a hint. It's only a hunch I have.

Comment: Doesn't it just follow from the definition of Riemann integral $$\int_{a}^{b} {f(x) dx} := \sup\left\{ \sum f(t_i) (x_i - x_{i+1}) \right\}$$ where the sup is taken over the $t_i$ and $x_i$ satisfying $a \leq x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n = b$ and each $t_i \in [x_i, x_{i+1}$]?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: I had also found this $x(k,n) = \frac{k}{n}$, but I don't think it works. I'll try this method too. Thanks a lot

Comment: According to wolfram alpha, this sum does not exist due to singularity at some points.